# How can AsyncTask be RUNNING yet not work?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a nested AsyncTask. This simple example is proof that they work: http://pastebin.com/0R9Cfxx1

However, in my production code, my nested AsyncTask returns getStatus == AsyncTask.RUNNING
yet, doInBackground() does not execute.

How can this be?

Comment: That should be crashing -- you can only create and execute an `AsyncTask` from the main application thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand AsyncTask, you're supposed to run it from the main application thread, which creates a separate thread where "doInBackground()" runs. Now, if you run a nested AsyncTask inside another AsyncTask, you would have a minimum of three threads total: main app thread, first AsyncTask thread and second AsyncTask thread. They will all run in parallel, which breaks the idea of "nestedness".
I believe the best way would be to refactor your code to use only one AsyncTask.

Comment: You're right to note that AsyncTask should always be called from the main thread.  In addition, since Honeycomb, AsyncTasks no longer draw from a threadpool, but are executed sequentially on the same thread.  So even if the OP is not getting an error for nesting his AsyncTasks, the inner one will not execute until after the outer is done on newer devices.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html